# Is there a maximum to the number of elements in std::bitset?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a maximum to the number of elements in an `std::bitset`?

In my code (VC++2010) `1<<20` crashes with a stack overflow, but `1<<19` works.

(I'm dealing with huge inputs.)

Comment: Related: [Define a large bitset in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780112/define-a-large-bitset-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see this has nothing to do with the maximum number of elements supported in `bitset` but has to do with the amount of memory that can be allocated on stack. On VS normally,  the maximum memory that can be allocated on stack is 1 MB and if you cross this limit then you get stack overflow. If you require more than this amount of memory, then I would suggest to allocate memory from heap using `new` rather than allocating on stack. In such case, the memory allocation will fail only when `new` truly runs out of memory.

Comment: Making the large object `static` usually works. Most operating systems can handle large executable binary images/global objects just fine, and I prefer not to resort to the heap.