# convert vector<bool> to int

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a `vector` of `bool` which I want to copy in a `int` container of bigger size. Is there a fast way to do this?

To clarify, is there a smarter way to achieve this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cassert>


inline size_t bool2size_t(std::vector<bool> in) {
    assert(sizeof(size_t)*CHAR_BIT >= in.size());
    size_t out(0);

    for (size_t vecPos = 0; vecPos < in.size(); vecPos++) {
        if (in[vecPos]) {
            out += 1 << vecPos;
        }
    }

    return out;
} 

int main () {
    std::vector<bool> A(10,0);
    A[2] = A[4] = 1;

    size_t B = bool2size_t(A);

    std::cout << (1 << 2) + (1 << 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
}
```

I'm looking for something like a `memcpy` which I can use on a subbyte level.

Comment: you want to copy a vector to another vector?

Comment: Depending on whether you need a dynamically sized container, you should consider using std::bitset instead, with its to_ulong() method.

Comment: I wan't to copy the memory of `vector<bool>` into an `int` which was set to zero. The important part is that the size of it might be not divable by 8.

Comment: @staticx: `vector<bool>`, unfortunately, isn't really a `vector`. Among others, it's implementation-defined whether you can get a `ForwardIterator` from it or not...

Comment: With C++11, you could probably use `std::hash()` on your boolean vector to achieve what you want.

Comment: @jxh. Sorry now you lost me. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure I entirely understand your question. If you just want to turn the boolean vector into a number that has a particular form if it fits within a certain integer type, `std::hash()` might do it for you. If you want something else, then...

Comment: @jxh. Yes exactly that is what I want. But I'm afraid I can still not follow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example using C++11:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<bool> b(10,0);
    b[2] = b[4] = 1;
    int i;
    i = accumulate(b.rbegin(), b.rend(), 0, [](int x, int y) { return (x << 1) + y; });
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Another solution that uses GCC internals for `vector<bool>` and is more efficient:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<bool> b(10,0);
    b[2] = 1;
    b[4] = 1;
    auto p = b.begin()._M_p;
    cout << *p << endl;
}
```

Note though that it is not recommended to use `vector<bool>` since it is a problematic specialization of `vector<T>` and has a slightly different API. I recommend using `vector<char>` instead, or creating your own `Bool` wrapper class with implicit cast to and from `bool`.

Comment: Are you positive this is going to work? I was once taught to basically stay away from any kind of iterators in relation to `vector<bool>`...

Comment: I didn't do any performance rating but isn't this about as slow as the loop? Maybe I'm wrong tough and I misunderstood something.

Comment: You are right, it will likely be as slow. I thought by "smarter way" you meant shorter, not faster.

Comment: @magu_ - I added a more efficient solution. It only works for gcc though.

Comment: Just be aware that the solution is implementation specific and probably not portable across compilers. For example, `clang` will *not* compile that code

Answer (score 4):

The implementation may store the `vector<bool>` as a bit set the way you want, but it is not required to do so. If you can change the type, look at the [`bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) template class, which works the same way, but implements e.g. `to_ulong`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156538/how-can-stdbitset-be-faster-than-stdvectorbool).

Edit: If [Boost](http://www.boost.org) is OK, there is [dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), which will do the chunking for you if you need to store more than a `unsigned long` can hold.

Comment: Hm I was trying to avoid bitset since I need to dynamically allocate the vector. Is it possible to dynamically allocate bitset - I don't need to resize it.

Comment: Well, an unsigned long will only hold 64 bits. If you exceed that you would have to use some other means, such as chunking them.

Comment: Hm yes, true. I don't really want to use boost. But I might simply implement `bitset<sizeof(size_t)*CHAR_BIT>` and live with the overhead. There are luckely not so many in memory of them at once.