# How to set bits?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a remote service that receives a number of parameters and an integer to flag which ones are null:

```
byte<(param_count + 7)/8> null bitmap
```

I've tried a naive implementation but since I've no experience in bit shifting I'd rather not show it.

So, given a vector of booleans, how can I create my bit map?

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a bitmap. Just like `std::bitset`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: How do I turn an `std::vector<bool>` into an integer?

Comment: If you use an `bitset` you can use the method `to_ulong`. The vector<bool> implementation may use a bitset under the hood but it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `param_count` is known at compile time you can use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Here is an example:

```
// Define a bitmap with 'param_count + 7' elements
std::bitset<param_count + 7> b;

// Set the fifth bit, zero is the first bit
b[4] = 1;

// Convert to 'unsigned long', and the casting it to an int.
int a = int(b.to_ulong());
```

If `param_count` is **not** known at compile time, you can use [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). Here is another example:

```
// Define a bitmap with 'param_count + 7' elements
std::vector<bool> b(param_count + 7);

// Set the fifth bit, zero is the first bit
b[4] = 1;

// Convert to 'int'
int a = std::accumulate(b.rbegin(), b.rend(), 0, [](int x, int y) { return (x << 1) + y; });
```

The conversion from `std::vector<bool>` to `int` is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24994714/2378300).

Comment: @Rakete1111 You are right, I'm adding a `vector<bool>` version.

Comment: param_count is not known at compile time.