# Faster lookup than std::set

Tags: c++, stdset

I need a faster membership lookup for some legacy packet processing code which needs to identify if a packet with a particular ID is in a particular list.

The list is only updated every few seconds while the packet matching happens very very often, so lookup performance is more important than insertion/deletion etc.

General Flow:

```
forall(special_PacketIDs)
{
  pktIdSet.insert(theSpecialPktId)
}

while (1)
{
  pkt = readPkt();
  pktID = getPktIdOfPkt(pkt);

  if ( aSpecialPkt(pktID) )
    doSomething();
}
```

And right now, `aSpecialPkt(pktId)` is defined as:

```
bool PktProcessor::aSpecialPkt(unsigned short pid)
{
  return pktPidSet.find(pid) != pktPidSet.end();
}
```

gprof reports a lot of time spent in the std::set::find()

The range of pktId is only 8192 possible values.  Allocate a linear array would be much faster at the expense of memory, something like:

```
class LinearSet
{
public:
  void insert(pid) { mPktIdSet[pid] = true; }
  bool elementExists(pid)  { return mPktIdSet[pid]; }
private:
  bool mPktIdSet[8192];
}
```

My question is whether there is a more "C++" way of doing this while maintaining top performance?

Comment: Did you try `std::unordered_set` or just `std::vector<bool>`?

Comment: Right now the set is defined as std::set<u_short>.  But seems unordered_set is only available in C++11, which this old code won't work without a lot of work.

Comment: @Danny: The complexity for find of a std::set is logarithmic and for a std::unordered_set  constant on average (worst case linear)

Comment: @DieterLücking You are right. I think I should stop posting stupid things around here....I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know that there are precisely 8192 possibilities, your best bet is probably `std::bitset<8192>`, which will use a kilobyte and is very cache-friendly.

Comment: Excellent choice. Just adding, for future reference, that if the size is much much much larger, and some falses are OK, then a [bloom filter](https://github.com/mavam/libbf) might be appropriate.

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @AmiTavory Very nice suggestion - a good use-case for the elusive bloom filter. :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::bitset<8192>` is a good choice, but it really depends on your platform as well as the number of special packet IDs. See this question: [Choosing between set<int> vs. vector<bool> vs. vector<boolean_t> to use as a bitmap (bitset / bit array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155847/choosing-between-setint-vs-vectorbool-vs-vectorboolean-t-to-use-as-a-bit)

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks!